# Choosing the right design pattern for data conversion, validation

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring

I have the below architecture.

1. Get data from User
2. Validate data
3. Store data in db

To simplify, let us assume data is of type Invoice. I have defined Invoice as an interface

```
Invoice () {
getInvoiceId ();
getInvoiceAmount();
...
....
}
```

In one of my implementations, the input from user is xml and in another it is json
Similarly I have two databases, one stores the invoice as xml and another as json

So I implement the Invoice interface twice as

```
InvoiceXml () {
xml _invoiceData;
getInvoiceId() {
return _invoiceData.id;
}

InvoiceJson () {
json _invoiceData;
getInvoiceId() {
return _invoiceData.id;
}
```

Now my main class accepts an instance of Invoice interface.

```
main(Validator validator, DAO db) 
{
   Invoice invoice = inputs.getInvoice();
   if (invoice instanceOf InvoiceXml {
    validator.validateXml(invoice);
    db.insertXml(invoice);
   }
   else //similar for Json
}
```

Now the concern I have is that validator and db both actually need the json/xml representation of invoice but since I depend only on the Invoice interface I have to downcast Invoice before passing it to validate and db.

I am not sure of how to design this in a better way. I was thinking of changing the Invoice interface to a POJO but there are many fields on the Invoice (getInvoiceId and getInvoiceAmount are the common ones used) so I have to internally store the invoice as an xml or json value only.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be adding `validate` method to `Invoice` interface and implement it properly on implementations `InvoiceXml` and `InvoiceJson`. But that merge two concepts: model and validation. Another approach to have interface `Validator` with method `validate` to separate from model and implement two datasource specific validation methods.

Comment: I have a prototype using a Validator interface but how do I enforce the criteria that I have to use XmlValidator when I want to validate InvoiceXml without needing to downcast

Comment: interface `invoice.validate(Validator v)` and xmlImplementation `validate(Validator v) { v.validateXml(this) }`